# Fancyhdr: unwanted different header fonts in ToC and normal text

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

The header font in my ToC is different than the header font in the document. How can I change that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color,
            mathptmx,
            fancyhdr,tikz}

\definecolor{myblue}{rgb} {0,0,0}%{0.15,0.15,0.25}

\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{
\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[R]{\color{myblue} \changefont{ppl}{m}{n}  \rightmark \hspace{-20mm}}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{myblue} \hrule width 185mm 
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Testchapter}
\section{Testsection}
%several chapters and sections

\end{document}
```

Please have a look at the picture below...
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is better to use `scrlayer-scrpage`. This package is also part of the KOMA-Script bundle:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0,0,0}%{0.15,0.15,0.25}

\usepackage[
    headwidth=\the\paperwidth-\the\hoffset-1in-\the\oddsidemargin:0pt,
    headsepline,
    automark,
    markcase=upper
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\rightmark\hspace{5mm}}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont\color{myblue}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument
\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument
\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument
\end{document}
```